# How to check PageOrientation.Portrait and PortraitUp and PortraitDown at once?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

the `PageOrientation` enum has some values like `Portrait`, `PortraitUp`, `PortraitDown`, `Landscape` and so on..

But for me no matter if it is portrait up or down so I can do this:

```
    if (this.Orientation == PageOrientation.Portrait
        || this.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp
        || this.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitDown)
```

but as they are zero based numbers, I know we can check these all in a shorter way. How can I do that? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check in PhoneApplicationPage Orientation Changed event.

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged
(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Hope it helps